# How to make share service for activate route in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular9

I am using **Angular 9**, there are 4 components in my app which has some redundant code of activate route.

The below piece of code is using in 6 components:-

```
 this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.selectedDepart = params['department'];
      this.access = this.selectedDepart === 'admin' ? 'full' : this.getAccess(this.selectedDepart);
      this.fetchData();
    });
```

I want something to put above code in one place and make it shared service. So, I can use it in different components.

I cannot figure out to create shared service for it and how to use it in different components?

Comment: You work with this a three times in subscription. Is this also in each component?

Comment: @ThorstenRintelen yes, I have used above subscription code in each component.

Comment: Yes, but has each component the same fetchData method? oder a property "selectedDepart"?

Comment: yes, each component has selectedDepart, access properties and fetchData method, inside method has different login.

Comment: ok, so, if in the subscribe happens different things, you only can put "this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe" into an service - and i think this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `shared.service.ts` and there you can have a method e.g. `getParamsData()` and `getAccess()` method also you can move to the shared service

service can be like

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService{
   getParamsData(){
       this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
              this.selectedDepart = params['department'];
              let access = this.selectedDepart === 'admin' ? 'full' : 
              this.getAccess(this.selectedDepart);
              return access;
    });
  }
}
```

And in the component you can do like:

```
export class YourComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(
     private sharedService:SharedService
  ){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.access=this.sharedServie.getParamsData();
  }

}
```